# MySql: Concatenate 2 columns if condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have the following data set:

```
CREATE TABLE division (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  division VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO division (division) VALUES ("Division1"), ("Division2"), ("Division3"), ("Division4");

CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  divisionID INT
) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO product (product, divisionID) VALUES ("Product1", 3), ("Product1", 1), ("Product2", 2), ("Product3", 4);
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Concat(product,' ',division) as 'product'
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN division d ON d.id = p.divisionID
ORDER BY product;
```

Above query pulls the following records:

```
Product
------------------
Product1 DIvision1
Product1 Division3
Product2 Division2
Product3 Division4
```

**Q:** How can I modify the query so that only the duplicate `Products` would be concatenated with their `Division`, and unique products would be left as is, like below example?

```
Product
------------------
Product1 Division1
Product1 Division3
Product2
Product3
```

Comment: Well done for providing a clear example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very literal solution...

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',p.product,CASE WHEN total > 1 THEN d.division ELSE NULL END) name 
  FROM product p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN division d 
    ON d.id = p.divisionid   
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT product
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM product 
        GROUP 
           BY product
     ) x 
    ON x.product = p.product
 ORDER
    BY p.product,d.division;
```